# Let $ \ G \ $ be a connected plane graph with $ \ v \ $ vertices and $ \ e \ $ edges

Tags: graph-theory

Let $ \ G \ $ be a connected plane graph with $ \ v \ $ vertices and $ \ e \ $ edges so that every vertex lies on one face of size $ \ 6 \ $ , one face of size $ \ 6 \ $ and one face of size $ \ 8 \ $. Let $ \ f_4,f_6, f_8 \ $ be the number of faces of size $ \ 4,6,8 \ $ respectively. Then

(i) Express $ \ e \ $ in terms of $ \ v \ $ i.e., how many edges are incident with each vertex?

(ii) Express $ f_4,f_6,f_8 \ $ in terms of $ \ v \ $

(iii) Use (i) and (ii) to determine $ \ v \ $

(iv) Finally determine $ e,f_4,f_6,f8 \ $

**Answer:**

Let $ \ G \ $ be a connected graph such tha

number of edges $ \ =e \ $,

number of vertices $ \ =v \ $,

Let $ \ f= \ $ number of faces.

By Euler's formula,

$ v-e+f=2 \ $

Now I think,

$ f=f_4+f_6+f_8 \ $

**But now I can not proceed to answer the questions.**

I am not getting way to answer.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: You have not yet used the information given in the problem that "every vertex lies on..."

Comment: how to implement that information to answer the question?  can you do little more?